# ORDER BY Alphanumeric sort

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, natural-sort

I want to ORDER BY data in the following sequence:

- Number-Number
- Alpha-Number
- Alpha with no dash

I have the following sort:

- 120-1
- 120-2
- 120-10
- Digital-1
- Digital-10
- Digital-2
- Wedding

This is the order I'm looking for, except the Digital (Alpha with dash) entries are not sorted by numbers after the dash.

After many attempts, here's my current sql statement:

```
SELECT SessionID, Identifier FROM Session 
ORDER BY 
CASE 
  WHEN CAST(Identifier AS INTEGER) THEN SUBSTR(Identifier,0, INSTR(Identifier, '-')) + CAST(SUBSTR(Identifier, INSTR(Identifier, '-')+1, 999) AS INTEGER) 
ELSE Identifier END
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: And what output do you get instead of the expected order?

Comment: The list under 'I have the following sort:'. Everything works except the Digital (Alpha with dash) is not listed by number.

Comment: can you use regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Order by strings having `-` in them so they appear first

2) Order by the first part before `-` in the strings containing `-` casting them as integers where applicable, Else order by the column itself

3) Order by the second part after `-` in the strings containing `-` casting them as integers where applicable, Else order by the column itself

```
select val
from t
order by 
 case when val like '%-%' then 1 else 2 end
,case when substr(val,1,instr(val,'-')-1) glob '*[0-9]*' 
      then cast(substr(val,1,instr(val,'-')-1) as integer) 
      when substr(val,1,instr(val,'-')-1) glob '*[a-zA-Z]*' 
      then substr(val,1,instr(val,'-')-1)
 else val end
,case when val like '%-%' then cast(substr(val,instr(val,'-')+1) as integer)
 else val end
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6cc85/1)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is somehow reconstructing the strings, but for the `order by`, you want something like this:

```
order by (case when CAST(Identifier AS INTEGER)  <> 0 then 1
               when Identifier like '%-%' then 2
               else 3
          end),
         identifier
```

Note:  This assumes that the numbers are never `0`.

Comment: Gordon, that gives me: 
120-1
120-2
120-10
Wedding
Digital-1
Digital-10
Digital-2
The all alpha (Wedding) is not at the bottom, and the Digital is still not sorted by number.

Comment: Gordon, that gives me: